# Animating NSView via NSBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation, core-animation

I have some NSBezierPath, and some NSView. I want to animate this NSView and use NEBezierPath as a animation path.
Creating CAKeyframeAnimation with path from UIBezierPath on IOS works fine for me, but for OSX it's not exactly the same.

Here is the code:

```
 self.headView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 50, 50)];
 [self.headView setWantsLayer:YES];
 [self.headView.layer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor].CGColor];

 [self.contentView addSubview:self.headView];

NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:pathStart];
[path curveToPoint:endPoint controlPoint1:[pointValue pointValue] controlPoint2:[pointValue pointValue]];

[path setLineWidth:3.0];
[[NSColor whiteColor] set];
[path stroke];

CAKeyframeAnimation *posAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
posAnim.path = [path quartsPath];
posAnim.duration = 1.0;
posAnim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
[self.headView.layer addAnimation:posAnim forKey:@"posAnim"];
```

Converting NSBezierPath to CGPathRef is from there: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-SW2

But it doesn't animate at all, here is the video: http://d.pr/v/glqQ

I don't getting what is the problem...

P.S. I prefer Keyframe animation because I would like to add some bouncing effect latter.

Comment: How is `self.headView.layer` created?  Are you sure it's not `nil`?

Comment: Updated with details about creating NSView

Comment: I think you are assuming that `NSView` is thin veneer over `CALayer` like `UIView` is?  It's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the superview of your headView also has a valid layer. Try this:

`self.contentView.wantsLayer = YES;`